# how do we find out obsolete SharePoint Groups in your site collection?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I got rid of several sites in past but forgot to delete the groups within them. Now i am trying to clear up those groups that were left over when i deleted the site. 
How do i go about cleaning up those orphaned groups from my site collection?

Answer (score 0):

So When ever you delete the site i hope you know those configurations will also be deleted.

[image]

Comment: not if your groups were used else where. for example site A is a parent  and site b is a child. Site b had groups x,y and z. If you add group x from your child site B to your parent site A. Then when you delete site b the child site, Group X still remains in its parent site A. That is what i am trying to find out. How many of those orphaned groups do we have and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now

So when ever you add the group from child site to parent site and if you want to delete that orphan groups

1. Open the site with SharePoint designer
2. if you observe the Permissions tab on the home page of share point designer there also you dont get the orphan group
3. Go to **Site groups** on the left panel of the share point designer
4. Delete the Orphan groups that were added from the child site

I tested it and it worked fine

[image]

Don't forget to vote the answer

Comment: we dont know where those groups exists that is the issue, if we knew we would go delete them manually and we have like 300-400 sites

Comment: Open the Parent site with share point designer and go to site groups there you find all the orphan groups with out description or if you have give a description while creating is also more easy to delete them

Comment: I am Referring to the orphaned groups only Just follow the procedure